# Checking if a unordered list contains a specific list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search

For example I have a list like this

```
<ul id='root'>
    <li> <a> Item0 </a> </li>
    <li> <a> Item1 </a> </li>
    <li> 
        <a> Item2X </a>
        <ul> 
            <li> <a> Item2.0 </a> </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and want to check if root contains the following item

```
<li> <a> Item2.0</a> </li>
```

We can use jquery the text value of a list item to compare for easiness. What is a good way to solve the above problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use jQuery [contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/):

```
var element = $('#root a:contains("Item2.0")');

if (element.length > 0) {
    // anchor was found containing "Item2.0" text
} else {
    // anchor was not found containing "Item2.0" text
}
```

Comment: awesome thanks, previously used the .find method with some logic, but thought there ought to be a simpler solution

Comment: is there a way to ignore space padding in the text when comparing. For example the root element might contain <"   Item2.0   "> and want that as a match when using the target node <"Item2.0">. Hope that was clear

Comment: not without using regular expressions. if you just use `contains("Item2.0")` it will find `<"Item2.0">` as well as `<" Item2.0 ">`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `:has` and `:contains`.

```
var hasItem = !!$("#root:has(a:contains(Item2.0))").length;
```